# Email field UI disappeared on formbuilder forms

Tags: forms, formbuilder, ui

When I am editing a FormBuilder (afform) form or viewing the form on the front-end, email fields no longer render an input box. I recently upgraded to 5.65.1, but I'm not sure if that was the cause or not. Here is the missing input field in the editor:

[image: AFForm editor]

And here it is on the front-end:
[image]

Any ideas? I'm running the WordPress version of CiviCRM if that matters.